# How to verify the user input for a random sized range in python

Tags: python, range

UPDATE:  How would I check that the "upperInteger" was indeed higher than the "lowerInteger"?

I'm looking to create a range from user input and have it not only verify the input is correct, but also to not allow the user to move forward until an acceptable input is received.  I believe a while loop should be used, but I'm not sure on how to implement one with an indeterminate range size.

The code is simply going to append the prime numbers inside of the range to a list which will then be printed.

```
prime_range = []
try:
    lowerInteger = int(input("Enter lower range limit: "))
    upperInteger = int(input("Enter upper range limit: "))
except:
    print("Invalid input.  Please input an integer and try again.")

else:
    for i in range(lowerInteger, (upperInteger + 1)):
        ##Test if i is a prime number
        primeflag = True
        for j in range (2,i):
            if(i % j == 0):
                primeflag = False
                break
        
        if (primeflag == True):
            prime_range.append(i)


print(prime_range)
```

Comment: i think no need to use else part here

Comment: Interesting.  So all I would need to do is take away the "else" and remove the indent from the "for"?

Comment: yeah like why use else part even as you know that with while and try except you take the user input as int and you proced with those input so there is no second condition which need to be taken care of

Answer (score 1):

You can use a boolean variable to know when the user inserted acceptable values:

```
prime_range = []

correct = False
while not correct:
    try:
        lowerInteger = int(input("Enter lower range limit: "))
        upperInteger = int(input("Enter upper range limit: "))
        correct = True
    except:
        print("Invalid input.  Please input an integer and try again.")

else:
    for i in range(lowerInteger, (upperInteger + 1)):
        ##Test if i is a prime number
        primeflag = True
        for j in range(2, i):
            if i % j == 0:
                primeflag = False
                break

        if primeflag == True:
            prime_range.append(i)


print(prime_range)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track with a while loop.

To make things easier I would break out the input fetching as it's own function. In this function you can validate all the rules for the inputs.

```py
def parse_inputs():
    while True:
        lower = input("Enter lower range limit: ")
        if not lower.isnumeric():
            print("lower range must be an integer. Please try again.")
            continue
        lower = int(lower)

        upper = input("Enter upper range limit: ")
        if not upper.isnumeric():
            print("upper range must be an integer. Please try again.")
            continue
        upper = int(upper)
        
        if upper < lower:
            print("lower range must be less than upper range. Please try again.")
            continue
        
        return lower, upper
```

Now you can use this in your loop:

```py
lower, upper = parse_inputs()
for i in range(lower, upper + 1):
    ...
```